# Add extra details Woocommerce order edit pages in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Hi I am using Woocommerce version 3.2.6. We have some orders.

I want to add one extra details to orders when the `product id` is `123` in the order edit page in wordpress backend.

I wanto add this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/new-view/?id=<?php echo $order_id?;>">Click here to view this</a>
```

ie: We have **order[order id =3723]** , and the ordered item id is **123**.

Then in `http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=3723&action=edit`, I want to add the following link below the corresponding item details:

```
"<a href="http://example.com/new-view/?id=<?php echo $order_id?;>">Click here to view this</a>"
```

How we can do this ?

Which hook is suitable for this. Actually I am searching in https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html.

And I found Class `WC_Meta_Box_Order_Items`. But i don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct code **for WooCommerce version 3+** to add a custom link just after line items and only on backend is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'custom_link_after_order_itemmeta', 20, 3 );
function custom_link_after_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ) {
    // Only for "line item" order items
    if( ! $item->is_type('line_item') ) return;

    // Only for backend and  for product ID 123
    if( $product->get_id() == 123 && is_admin() )
        echo '<a href="http://example.com/new-view/?id='.$item->get_order_id().'">'.__("Click here to view this").'</a>';
}
```

Tested and works

> 1) **Important:** Limit the code to order items "line item" type only, to avoid errors on other order items like "shipping", "fee", "discount"...
>
> 2) From the `WC_Product` object to get the **product id** you will use `WC_Data` **`get_id()`** method.
>
> 3) To get the **Order ID** from `WC_Order_Item_Product` object you will use `WC_Order_Item` method **`get_order_id()`**.
>
> 4) You need to add **`is_admin()`** in the `if` statement to restrict the display in backend.

Comment: Amazing, after hours of searching I finally found your comment, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Order Items** Meta Box uses `html-order-items.php` to loop through Order Items which in turn uses `html-order-item.php` to display each item.

For your purpose you should look inside `html-order-item.php` for exact place where you would want to insert your code snippet.

I assume `woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta` action hook is ideal as it will show the link just below meta information of the item. *(In case you want to display the link before item meta than use `woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta`.)*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'wp177780_order_item_view_link', 10, 3 );
function wp177780_order_item_view_link( $item_id, $item, $_product  ){
    if( 123 == $_product->id ) {
        echo "<a href='http://example.com/new-view/?id=" . $order->id . "'>Click here to view this</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2, Missing argument 3 for wp177780_order_item_view_link() in /home/exmple/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 974

Comment: Oops. That was a rush job. Missed to add priority and accepted arguments count. Check the updated code.